# The program to form words with pointers Pascal. Cannot find an error

Tags: pointers, dynamic, pascal

I 've written a program to form words with pointers and dynamic data structures

But it does not work and show an error at line 19 ( element is not declared in the type of pointer ) Help me please finish it.
I will be grateful

```
program pointers;

type
  zv = ^pointer;

  pointer = record
    element : char;
    next : zv;
  end;

var
  vlan : zv;  {separate element}
  vslov : zv;  { pointer for word }
  symbol : char;

begin
  readln(symbol);
  new(vslov);

  vslov^.element := symbol;
  vslov^.next := nil;
  vlan := vslov;

  while symbol <> '.' do
    begin
      read(symbol);
      new(vlan^.next);
      vlan := vlan^.next;
      vlan^.element := symbol;
      vlan^.next := nil;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: I recommend this article for learning how to debug small programs:  http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer` is a pre-defined type name. It is the type used to represent an untyped pointer. So `zv` is a pointer to a pointer. And the pre-defined type `pointer` is not a record and therefore cannot be used with the member access operator `.`.

Solve the problem by choosing a different name for your record type.